# Pay with Amazon - Shipping/Billing Addresses Blank

Tags: magento-1.9, amazon

I'm trying to get Pay with Amazon set up, and everything seems to work fine except that, during checkout, Magento doesn't seem to display the billing address or shipping address. I've run through the process in Sandbox mode and the transaction goes through without an issue, but for whatever reason it just isn't displaying the address information on the checkout screen. Has anyone else experienced this and know how to solve it?